# CONCAT to concat two $_GET function

Tags: php, symfony, dql

*i have written insert code in doctrine like this
$social = new Entities\SocialKeyword;

```
        $social->setEventId($_GET["eventId"]);
        $social->setHashtag($_GET["hashtag"]);

        $this->em->persist($social);
        $this->em->flush();
```

now i want to merge $_GET["eventId"] and $_GET(hashtag) and both are septated by '-' and insert it into prime colum in table.

i written it like this but its not working.

```
$social->setPrime(CONCAT($_GET["eventId"],'-', $_GET["hashtag"]));
```

need help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP does not have a minimal understanding of the used laguage, and obviously did not search the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP concatenation operator is ('.') but you used (',').
Try with this:

```
$concate_value = $_GET["eventId"].'-'.$_GET["hashtag"];
$social->setPrime($concate_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

First `$_GET(hashtag)` is looking wrong it should `$_GET["hashtag"]`. Simple use dot `(.)` operator for string concatenation

```
$_GET["eventId"] . '-' . $_GET["hashtag"]
```

In your code

```
$social->setPrime($_GET["eventId"] . '-' . $_GET["hashtag"]);
```